# Moving wordpress from server to localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, transfer

I have followed the second procedure described in this [article](http://www.premiumwebbloghosting.com/2012/07/moving-wordpress-from-hosting-to-localhost.html) to move the wordpress installation from the server to localhost, so as to start using Git. As soon as I browsed to localhost I got lots of errors, started fixing them and right now  whenever I visit the local site url it redirects me to localhost/wordpress-website-bouwen giving me an Object not found page. Have you got any idea why this happens? Where should I look for the error?

Comment: Why do people use wordpress...?

Comment: I dislike it too...I was to do Android dev work and was given Wordpress tasks. Now I do not know where to begin debugging...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey I remember running into this. Check out this link, it should solve your problems - [Search and Replace 2](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/)

Basically, wordpress saves many of your references to images, links etc in the db. As a result, when you migrate the database over to a new host (be it locally or otherwise), wordpress is going to reference the web url stored in the database.

What Search and Replace does is asks you for the current standard url and asks you to also put in the new one. So for example if you are on site `gimmemychicken.com` and you move it locally then you will want to put `gimmemychicken.com` in the current url and in the new url input, you would put `localhost`.

All you have to do is take the Search and Replace file -> place it somewhere in your directory -> navigate to it in a browser -> and fill out all the required info.

**As a side note:** Sometimes after sr2 runs you need to go back to your permalinks settings and resave them (don't worry about changing them, just click on save/update)

Comment: thanks for the lengthy comment, I found out about this Search and Replace 2 through Tom's answer, moved it to the root of my installation and ran it. I replaced the address "beta.fray.it" with "localhost", but I saw no change in the end...like nothing happened :(((((

Comment: Was the wordpress installation at a subfolder? ie - beta.fray.it/subfolder/wordpressinstall

Comment: No, it's under the beta folder on the server, so you can view it on http://beta.fray.it. I think the db is not my problem here, it's all those numerous changes I need to make to the PHP files. I am doing this cause I wanted to use Git while developing, but now I am thinking of using a central version control tool, so as to avoid all this hassle.

Comment: Well if you migrate the site locally, you will HAVE to do a search and replace and then refresh your permalinks in the wp backend. To make sure your search and replace worked take a look at references to things you are dynamically calling in - like stylesheets, etc. Then see if the url looks correct. Sorry if any of this is stuff you've already done, without code - trying to isolate this is hard. In regards to your php files, all you will have to do is go into your wp-config.php file and modify the db name/username/pass to match what you have locally. At that point things should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide to move wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress , easier with fewer errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , It is working for me. set your database home URL and site URL as localhost/your folder/ and  properly config your file . if you using wamp in your task bar go to Wamp->Apache->Apache Module-> and drag down there in one function as rewrite module. click OK. restart wamp. It will get run through your localhost.